# I have an input as A:2;b:5;e:7;d:9;m:10 and I want output as in table format using talend

Tags: talend

I have an input as below
A:2;b:5;e:7;d:9;m:10
and I want output as in table format
A   B   E   D   M
2   5   7   9   10

I am completely new to talend. Please help me?
Thanks in advance...

Comment: could you clarify the output format you need ? It is unclear as it is stated now.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my answer:-

Its a two component solution. Please take tFixedFlwoInput and create two columns col1 and col2 in the schema and set the component properties as shown in the below image:-

[image]

Pass the rows via main link to the tJavaFlex and there use the 7 liner simple logic code as shown in the below snapshot will give the desired output.

[image]